# Make div fill height of parent with dynamic sibling

Tags: html, image, css, responsive-design

I have an html structure with a container and two children. The first child is a dynamically sized image and the second is an also dynamically sized div.

[image: Visualization]
I want two things:

- if the two children are smaller than the total height of the main element, the second child should fill the empty space
- if the two children are taller than the total height of the main element, the main element should expand to fit the two divs and the footer should be pushed down

Comment: You will have to use javascript for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use flexbox with flex-direction column and a set **min**-height on your main, then allow the second child to grow and not the first

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}

main{
  min-height:500px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column
}

.div1{
  flex:0;
  height: 100px; /*for demonstration only, leave it undeclared (auto)*/
  border:2px solid orange; 
  color:orange
}

.div2{
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid lightblue;
  color:lightblue;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="div1"><p>image with dinamic height</div>
  <div class="div2"><p>div with information about the page</div>
</main>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use flexbox until 2020 at least. It is recently supported by major web browsers, with a total market share of aprox. 35% (the ones having versions that support flexbox)

Comment: @JorgeeFG IE10 with `-ms-` prefixes should not complain with what's suggested. IE9 is out of the game? Well not *yet* market share at 13% (still high for 2018) our fault (and *theirs*). Microsoft stopped support for 8,9,10 **two** years ago! (Now struggles with 11 and Edge). Providing programming "support" for such browsers is like openly agreeing on your users to be infestated by malware - instead of providing an alternative browser - could be punishable in some countries :) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsforbusiness/end-of-ie-support.

Comment: @JorgeeFG really? Support for flexbox is pretty much perfect all around. https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox  And this thing will fallback without an issue, the 'main' will  be just display:block with a set min-height, div1 and 2 will be just block level elements with auto height. It's not so terrible.

Comment: @FacundoCorradini yeah, forgot to mention that too :)

Comment: @FacundoCorradini BTW min-height - no. The viewport matters here. Use `html, body` with `margin:0; height:100%;`